# Hide and Show MapBox annotation Image View based On the zoom level

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

[image: MapBox MglMapView]

How to hide and show the `MapBox` annotation views based on the zoom levels

-> i am using the `MkMapView` MkAnnotationView Hide and show working fine

-> But using `MapBox`  Hide and show Not working
-> Hear i am writing This code for `mapKit` Working

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {


  let mglVisiableAnnArray = self.mglMap.visibleAnnotations

                        if mglVisiableAnnArray != nil {

                            for annotation in mglVisiableAnnArray!
                            {
                                if self.mglMap.zoomLevel < 12.5
                                {
                                    self.mglMap.view(for:annotation)?.isHidden = true

                                }else{
                            self.mglMap.view(for:annotation)?.isHidden = false

                                }
                            }
                        }
}
```

Please Help Me how to hide and show the MapBoxAnnotationView based On the MapBox Zoom level 
Thanks @mannaiah

Comment: Could you share where you are using that code? Also, are your annotations interactive?

Comment: iam using the above the code in 
 func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
}

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `MGLPointAnnotations` to a Shape source which would add all your annotations to the map.

```
var myAnnotations = [your annotations...]

private func configureSource(style: MGLStyle) -> MGLShapeSource {
    var annotations = [MyCustomAnnotation]()
    for annotation in self.myAnnotations {
      if let myAnnotation = annotation as? MyCustomAnnotation {
        annotations.append(myAnnotation)
        let imageName = myAnnotation.annotationImageName
        if let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
          style.setImage(image, forName: imageName)
        }
      }
    }

    return MGLShapeSource(identifier: "myAnnotations", features: annotations, options: nil)
  }
```

```
func configureSymbolLayer(source: MGLShapeSource) -> MGLSymbolStyleLayer {
  let symbols = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "identifier", source: source)
  symbols.iconImageName = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "annotationImageName")

  if self.mapBoxView.zoomLevel < zoomThreshold {
    symbols.iconOpacity = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "0.0")
  } else {
    symbols.iconOpacity = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "1.0")
  }

  return symbols
}
```

You then need to add the source and style in the `didFinishLoading style` delegate method.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
  guard let style = mapView.style else { return }

  let source = configureSource(style: style)
  style.addSource(source)
  style.addLayer(configureSymbolLayer(source: source))
}
```

`mapView`'s reload style function should be called by default when ever the region is changed but if not you might need to call it manually in `regionDidChanged` delegate method.